# What is the purpose of void* argument in sqlite3_exec

Tags: c, sqlite

I was reading the [documentation for  sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html), and I was wondering what the purpose of the `void*` parameter (4th parameter) is. The documentation says that it is relayed back to the 1st argument of the callback function, but I don't understand the purpose of this. I also see, [in an example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) that this relayed argument is simply ignored (it's even named `NotUsed` !).

I suspect that the intention behind the argument is to verify from where the callback function was called, although I cannot be sure as I am a beginner in both SQLite and the world of programming in general.

Comment: It allows you to pass more data to the callback function. Perhaps some context needed by the callback function for it to process the SQL response (only an example).

Comment: If the callback function is called, that `void *` will be passed as first argument

Comment: Such an argument should always be available in callback setups else, as you say, the callback has no context.  In OO languages, an object reference is often transferred using such a mechanism.

Comment: Side note: `sqlite3_exec()` is usually only appropriate for things like `CREATE TABLE` statements that don't generate any result rows. If you're actually using a callback function with it, you're probably going about the task wrong. Exceptions include printing out the results, in which case you might want to pass, say, a `FILE` pointer in that argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was reading the documentation for sqlite, and I was wondering what the purpose of the void* parameter (4th parameter) is. The documentation says that it is relayed back to the 1st argument of the callback function, but I don't understand the purpose of this. I also see, in an example that this relayed argument is simply ignored (it's even named NotUsed !).

The argument passed in fourth place is passed to the function *as is*, this is, it's never touched by the function.  This will allow you to pass global context to the callback by means of some kind of (not yet defined type, you will have to) structure, in which you define the global data your callback is going to use.  Let's say you just want to maintain a counter with the total number of calls the callback has been called to.  You cannot use a local variable, or you can use a global one.  But this last --using a global variable--  makes your function non-reentrant, so it cannot be used in a multithreading context, or you will have to protect mutual access by several callbacks.  This approach allows you to pass a pointer to a local variable, a pointer to a socket descriptor referencing a tcp connection to send the data through, a couple of object of this kind, grouped in a single structure, etc.

A callback is an inversion of control feature that you use to have finer control over a process, the process will call your callback at some point (one or several times), but you have no way to specify that you want the callback called with some global context you will provide.  This is the reason of that pointer.... the pointer will be passed, untouched, and also untouched the data it points to, to allow you to pass the needed context (e.g. a transaction information, or some file descriptor to use in some operation, that will remain open for the whole time the application is running)

From the documentation of the function link you provide, it seems that for the execution of the full set of statements you order sqlite to perform, it calls your callback to process *each of the rows emerging from the query.*  The purpose of the `void *` is to allow you to pass global information (e.g. the query used, global space to make some calculations, like adding or counting the number of registers processed, to hold the `FILE *` descriptor where to print logging data.... etc.